# Why the Overflow prperty doesnt work like I expect it to?

Tags: html, css

I've learned that when I use the property `overflow:auto;` when needed, it appends a scrollbar to the right side of the box (and if it is necessary, to the bottom too). You can see an example for that here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow_auto

But, in that case, the property is just getting the block to be higher:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    div {
        border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    }
    
    .clearfix {
        overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .img2 {
        float: right;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <p style="clear:right">Add a clearfix class with overflow: auto; to the containing element, to fix this problem:</p>
    
    <div class="clearfix"><img class="img2" src="w3css.gif" alt="W3Schools.com" width="100" height="140">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum...</div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Why doesn't it add a scrollbar in the second example, as it does at the first?

Comment: You did not specify a height, so the element is allowed to grow as high as the content demands it - and therefor there is nothing left that would overflow the element’s dimensions, so naturally no scrollbar needed either.

Comment: because it is a floating element, so the height of the object doesn't affect the container.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a **width** or **height** to use the overflow property